# get the latitude and longitude using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, latitude-longitude, city

I have a `textbox` in my page which gets a `location` name and `button` with text `getLat&Long`. Now on `clicking` my button I have to show an `alert` of `latitude` and `longitude` of the location in the `textbox`. Any suggestion?

please dont give me suggestion as googleapis b'coz its some stage limitations after this limit want to pay for this. 
this is my try with `googleapis`:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myIP(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
            var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '#city'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert("location : " + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 
          } else {
            alert("Something got wrong " + status);
          }
        });
});
}
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="myIP()">
<input type="text" id= "city">
<input id="btn" type="button" value="get Lat&Long" />
</body>
</html>
```

thanks.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: @plalx add my code. but i am use  `googleapis` i dont like this any other idea then suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the latitude and longitude from an address or location name (Geocoding) is complicated, so a third party service like google api is going to be needed.